# Using RxJava + Retrofit to make API requests for each item in a list

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to create an observable by chaining together multiple retrofit api calls. The steps are:

1. Get a list of json objects using api call
2. For each object in the list, make another api call to get further details about the item
3. Write data taken from this new detailed object to a file on the disk (this occurs for each item in the list)
4. Finally return an observable of a separate object that requires that a file was created for each of the previous objects

This is what I have so far:

```
public static Observable<DownloadedFiles> downloadFiles() {
    DownloadedFiles downloadedFiles = new DownloadedFiles();
    Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        return getRestService().getObjectList()
        .flatMapIterable(objects -> objects)
        .flatMap(objectLimited -> getRestService().getObject(objectLimited.getPath()))
        .doOnNext(objectFull -> {

            try {
                File file = new File();
                // Extract data from objectFull and write new file to disk
                // ...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }

            downloadedFiles.putFile(file);
        })
        .toList()
        .map(objects -> downloadedFiles)
        .finallyDo(() -> {
            subscriber.onNext(downloadedFiles);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        });
    });
}

@GET("/api/...")
Observable<List<Object>> getObjectList();

@GET("/api/.../{path}")
Observable<Object> getObject(@Path("path") String path);
```

Could someone please confirm that I have used the correct operators. Thanks .

Comment: Its a little difficult to tell what subscriber is in your example?

Comment: @alexwen, sorry I was missing a line. I've edited the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:  Removed the Observable.create, retrofit is already making an observable for you, you merely need to transform it.

Edit 2: you also shouldn't need to do anything with subscriber.onError, if an error gets thrown it will call subscriber.onError on its own.

Pretty good, Not sure why you went with flatmap observable. I would instead do flatmap to Observable::from, also collect is worth adding.  Basically I'm going to map 1 thing to many, then do some action, collect the many back into one and then subscribe to that one once I collected all items emitted.

```
public static Observable<DownloadedFiles> downloadFiles() {        
        return getRestService().getObjectList()
        .flatMap(Observable::from)
        .flatMap(objectLimited -> getRestService().getObject(objectLimited.getPath()))
        .doOnNext(objectFull -> {
            try {
                File file = new File();
                // Extract data from objectFull and write new file to disk
                // ...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                new IOException(e);
            }})
      .collect(() -> new DownloadFiles<>(), (files, object) -> {  files.add(object});
```

Comment: Thanks, where would I call subscriber.onNext and subscriber.onCompleted?

Comment: No need to.  onNext gets called with every emitted item through the chain, in your case there will only be 1 item emitted. As soon as that 1 emit (the downloadFiles) gets emitted onComplete will be called.  onError will be called if there is a problem anywhere in this chain.  So when you subscribe you'd probably do something like downloadFiles.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer(){}))

Comment: Great. Could you explain why an object is being added to files in collect()? Isn't that already taken care of my the last line in doOnNext?

Comment: removed that add.  Normally when working with observable streams you want to localize your data as much as possible.  By using collect, an object gets created which can only be affected by the stream.  By creating the downloadFile object outside of your stream you risk mutating it outside of the stream.  Just a little semantics, I overall like to go with the built in Rx solution rather than fitting more than 1 operation per aggregate

Comment: One thing to be careful with here is where are you saving the files? Is it a temp directory? If there is an error anywhere in your chain some of the files may be saved, some not, and you will just get the onError triggered from your Observable with no way of telling how much work was done or which files were saved.

Comment: Is there a way to delay the error? If an error occur i don't want whole chain to stop. i like to have the error at the end like, just like `concatDelayError()` .

Comment: i found `concatMapDelayError()` . should i use it when calling the first observable for list or for the second call on each individual call.

Comment: Second one. The first one is merely splitting a List into individual items. The second one is what makes the call. As a result you want the second one to delay the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think some like this should work for you. Instead of pulling in a Subject to emit it the DownloadedFile(s) to, you can just use the Observable from the REST service to map to each of the DownloadedFiles:

```
public static Observable<DownloadedFile> downloadFiles() {
    final Observable<Observable<FullObject>> observable =  getRestService().getObjectList()
            .flatMapIterable(objects -> objects)
            .map(objectLimited -> getRestService().getObject(objectLimited.getPath()));

    return  Observable.mergeDelayError(observable)
            .map(fullObject -> {
                try {
                    File file = new File("path");
                    // Extract data from objectFull and write new file to disk
                    // ...

                    return new DownloadedFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw OnErrorThrowable.from(OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(e, fullObject));
                }
            });
}
```

You may want to consider using mergeDelayError(map()) instead of flatMap if you want to emit successfully saved files before propagating any errors.

Comment: `Object objectToSave = getRestService().getObject(objectLimited.getPath());` wont work because the getRestService().getObject() returns an observable.